# How can I extract the start and end time from a date/time in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I would like to get the start and the end time from the rows of data.
The start time is the Activity_start and end time is the Activity_End on the table.
My table look like;

| Event_Time | Class | Activity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 13/12/2021 09:02 | ACTIVITY_START | Stock Audit |
| 13/12/2021 12:19 | ACTIVITY_END | Stock Audit |
| 13/12/2021 12:19 | ACTIVITY_START | Inventory |
| 13/12/2021 12:38 | LOGOUT | Inventory |
| 13/12/2021 12:38 | ACTIVITY_END | Inventory |
| 13/12/2021 12:47 | LOGIN | None |
| 13/12/2021 12:47 | ACTIVITY_START | Marshalling |
| 13/12/2021 12:47 | ACTIVITY_END | Marshalling |
| 13/12/2021 13:40 | ACTIVITY_START | Stock Audit |
| 13/12/2021 15:06 | ACTIVITY_END | Stock Audit |

I'm expected to have a table that look like;

| Date | Activity_Name | Start_Time | Eend_Time | Minutes_elapsed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 13/12/2021 | Stock Audit | 09:02 | 12:19 | ----- |
| 13/12/2021 | Inventory | 12:19 | 12:38 | ----- |
| 13/12/2021 | Marshalling | 12:47 | 12:47 | ----- |
| 13/12/2021 | Stock Audit | 13:40 | 15:06 | ----- |

Comment: An d if END is missing? Or there are two STARTs? (Also, please avoid ambiguous date formats like dd/mm/yyyy.)

Comment: Do you have any sort of unique Event identifier?

Comment: I've removed the reference to "timestamp" in your title. In SQL Server `timestamp` is a deprecated synonym for `rowversion`, which is a `binary(8)` value, *not* a date and time value. As such when talking about SQL Server the usage of "timestamp" can be confusing when you are in fact talking about a date and time value, *not* `timestamp` (`rowversion`).

Comment: Provided every Activity happens once a day just group by `Date` `Activity_Name` the events of interest.

Comment: No unique event identifier.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way, you pull *just the activity start and end rows*, then you can use `ROW_NUMBER()` to match up start and end pairs, and self-join:

```
;WITH src AS 
(
  SELECT Event_Time, Class, Activity,
    rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
    (PARTITION BY Activity, Class ORDER BY Event_Time, Class DESC)
  FROM dbo.TradingTable
  WHERE Class IN ('ACTIVITY_START', 'ACTIVITY_END')
)
SELECT [Date]          = CONVERT(date, before.Event_Time),
       Activity_Name   = before.Activity,
       Start_Time      = CONVERT(char(5), before.Event_Time, 108),
       End_Time        = CONVERT(char(5), after.Event_Time,  108),
       Minutes_elapsed = DATEDIFF(MINUTE, before.Event_Time, after.Event_Time)
FROM src AS before 
LEFT OUTER JOIN src AS after
  ON  before.rn        = after.rn
  AND before.Activity  = after.Activity
  AND after.Class      = 'ACTIVITY_END'
WHERE before.Class     = 'ACTIVITY_START'
ORDER BY [Date], Start_Time;
```

Results:

| Date | Activity_Name | Start_Time | End_Time | Minutes_elapsed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-12-13 | Stock Audit | 09:02 | 12:19 | 197 |
| 2021-12-13 | Inventory | 12:19 | 12:38 | 19 |
| 2021-12-13 | Marshalling | 12:47 | 12:47 | 0 |
| 2021-12-13 | Stock Audit | 13:40 | 15:06 | 86 |

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=441b9e0613aab228240a6c3c3ffffe45) (also deals with an "unfinished" event).

This will scan the table twice (or range scan whatever else you do inside `src` to limit the output, e.g. if you have a where clause on a date range). There are almost certainly ways to do this with a single scan but they will involve much more elaborate use of windowing functions, like this:

```
;WITH src AS 
(
  SELECT Event_Time, Class, Activity,
    rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
    (PARTITION BY Activity, Class ORDER BY Event_Time, Class DESC)
  FROM dbo.TradingTable
  WHERE Class IN ('ACTIVITY_START', 'ACTIVITY_END')
),
agg AS
(
  SELECT [Date]        = CONVERT(date, Event_Time),
         Activity_Name = Activity,
         Start_Time    = Event_Time,
         End_Time      = LEAD(Event_Time, 1) OVER 
                         (PARTITION BY Activity, rn ORDER BY Class DESC),
         newrn         = ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
                         (PARTITION BY Activity, rn ORDER BY Event_Time)
  FROM src
)
SELECT [Date],
       Activity_Name,
       Start_Time      = CONVERT(char(5), Start_Time, 108),
       End_Time        = CONVERT(char(5), End_Time,   108),
       Minutes_elapsed = DATEDIFF(MINUTE, Start_Time, End_Time)
FROM agg
WHERE newrn = 1
ORDER BY [Date], Start_Time;
```

- Updated [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1ace87794df9726629f62a88b95b54c6) with execution plans.